# How to I change the fixed billing amount from 199 to an amount specified by the database?

Tags: php, database, string, variables, billing

as of right now in my code when someone is getting billed, it is automatically generates it to cost 199. What I want to do now is change that so that instead of it automatically making it 199, it is the amount specified in the database. I thought the code I put in would work, but it doesn't and I'm not sure why. Instead of it making it cost anything, it just will make it cost 0.00 in the database, even though in the database I made new fields automatically start at 199.00, so I'm really not sure why it makes it 0.00. Any suggestions would be very appreciated. here is the code:

```
<?php
    include_once ("includes/config.php");
    include_once ("includes/functions.php");

    $magazine_listings = getAllMagazineListings ();
    if ($magazine_listings)
    {
        $exempt_agents = array ();
        $select2 = "SELECT `a_id`
                    FROM `agents`
                    WHERE `charge_cc` = 0";
        $res2 = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($select2) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
        if ($res2->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while ($row2 = $res2->fetch_assoc ())
            {
                $exempt_agents [] = $row2 ['a_id'];
            }
        }
        $rets = new PHRETS;

        $connect = $rets->Connect ($login, $un, $pw);

        if ($connect)
        {

            $L_UpdateDate = @date ("Y-m-d", time () - 2592000);
            while ($magazine_listing = $magazine_listings->fetch_assoc ())
            {
                // Search Residential
                $search = $rets->SearchQuery (
                    'Property',                             // Resource
                    'RE_1',                                     // Class
                    '(L_ListingID=' . $magazine_listing ['listing_id'] . '),(L_StatusCatID=2),(L_UpdateDate=' . $L_UpdateDate . '+)',
                    array(
                        'Format'    => 'COMPACT-DECODED',
                        'Select'    => 'L_ListingID, L_Class, L_AskingPrice, L_StatusCatID',
                        'Count'     => 1
                    )
                );
                print 'TotalRecordsFound='.$rets->TotalRecordsFound ().'<br>';
                //exit;
                if ($rets->TotalRecordsFound () > 0)
                {
                    while ($data = $rets->FetchRow ($search))
                    {
                        $mysqli = new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
                        if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
                        {
                            echo ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
                        }
                        $select = "SELECT `sh_id`, `listing_id`, `a_id`, `agent_mls_id`, `billed`
                                    FROM `sold_product`
                                    WHERE `listing_id` = '" . $data ['L_ListingID'] . "'";
                        $res = $mysqli->query ($select) or die ($mysqli->error . __LINE__);
                        if ($res->num_rows > 0)
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $billing_date = time () + 604800;
////////////////////////////The New Code/////////////////////////////////////////
                            $billing_cost = "SELECT `agent_billing_amount` FROM `agents`"; 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////        Old code here:      $billing_cost = 199;
////////////////////        This worked, it however just made 
////////////////////        it automatically 199. With the new code above, it makes it 0.00, 
////////////////////        even though in the database, none of the rows are at 0.00
////////////////////        $billing_cost = 199;    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                            if (in_array ($magazine_listing ['a_id'], $exempt_agents))
                            {
                                $insert = "INSERT INTO `sold_product`
                                            (`m_id`, `moveover_m_id`, `listing_id`, `a_id`, `agent_mls_id`, `billing_cost`, `billing_date`, `billed`, `charge`)
                                            VALUES ('" . $magazine_listing ['m_id'] . "', '" . $magazine_listing ['moveover_m_id'] . "', '" . $data ['L_ListingID'] . "', '" . $magazine_listing ['a_id'] . "', '" . $magazine_listing ['agent_mls_id'] . "', '" . $billing_cost . "', '" . $billing_date . "', 0, 0)";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $insert = "INSERT INTO `sold_product`
                                            (`m_id`, `moveover_m_id`, `listing_id`, `a_id`, `agent_mls_id`, `billing_cost`, `billing_date`, `billed`, `charge`)
                                            VALUES ('" . $magazine_listing ['m_id'] . "', '" . $magazine_listing ['moveover_m_id'] . "', '" . $data ['L_ListingID'] . "', '" . $magazine_listing ['a_id'] . "', '" . $magazine_listing ['agent_mls_id'] . "', '" . $billing_cost . "', '" . $billing_date . "', 0, 1)";
                            }
                            $mysqli->query ($insert) or die ($mysqli->error . __LINE__);
                            $insert_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
                            if ($insert_id > 0)
                            {
                                if (in_array ($magazine_listing ['a_id'], $exempt_agents))
                                {
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $agent = getAgentProfile ($magazine_listing ['a_id']);

                                    // Send Email
                                    $to = $agent ['email'];     
                                    $subject = "Listing Sold Notification!";

                                    // message
                                    $message = '
                                    <html>
                                        <head>
                                            <title>Notification!</title>
                                        </head>
                                        <body>
                                            <h3>Notification!</h3>
                                            <p>One of your products has been sold. Below are the details:</p>
                                            <table width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="30%">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td width="70%">&nbsp;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="right">MLS #</td>
                                                    <td>' . $data ['L_ListingID'] . '</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="right">Billing Cost:</td>
                                                    <td>$' . number_format ($billing_cost, 2) . '</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="right">Billing Date:</td>
                                                    <td style="font-weight: bold;">' . @date ("m/d/Y", $billing_date) . '</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <p><strong>Note:</strong> Billing Cost will be automatically charged from your Credit Card on the above specified Billing Date!</p>
                                            <p>
                                                --<br />
                                                Support<br />
                                            </p>
                                        </body>
                                    </html>
                                    ';

                                    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
                                    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                                    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

                                    // Mail it
                                    @mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
                                }

                                $delete = "DELETE FROM `magazine_listings`
                                            WHERE `ml_id` = '" . $magazine_listing ['ml_id'] . "'";
                                $mysqli->query ($delete) or die ($mysqli->error . __LINE__);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                $rets->FreeResult ($search);

            }
            $rets->Disconnect ();
        }
        else
        {
            $error = $rets->Error ();
            print_r ($error);
        }
    }
print 'done';   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

all you are doing here is binding an SQL query to a variable. But even if you ran it, it would return you an **array**. Try this:

```
$sql='SELECT `agent_billing_amount` FROM `agents`';
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result(); $row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$billing_cost = $row['agent_billing_amount'];
```

Change $con to your database connection variable

Comment: Well, I did what you said, but no such luck i'm afraid, any other suggestions?

Comment: add echos for the relevant variables, to ensure that you are connected and that your SQL query is returning some result(s), if you just copied and pasted this code it may not work as this is MYSQLi and you might be using PDO. did you change the $row['agent_billing_amount'] to match the field in your table in the database?